# outputLocation is not a valid S3 path. Athena Exception

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, s3-bucket

I am trying to execute athena query using c# athena driver.

```
Amazon.Athena.Model.ResultConfiguration resultConfig = new Amazon.Athena.Model.ResultConfiguration();
resultConfig.OutputLocation = "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testbucket/one/2018-02-06/";
//other inputs i have tried
//"s3://testbucket/one/2018-02-06/"
//testbucket

//Populate the request object
                Amazon.Athena.Model.StartQueryExecutionRequest queryExec = new Amazon.Athena.Model.StartQueryExecutionRequest();
                queryExec.QueryString = query.QueryString;
                queryExec.QueryExecutionContext = queryExecutionContext;
                queryExec.ResultConfiguration = resultConfig;

StartQueryExecutionResponse athenaResponse = athenaClient.StartQueryExecution(queryExec);//throws exception
```

Exception for different cases:

> 1. outputLocation is not a valid S3 path. Provided https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testbucket/one/2018-02-06/
> 2. Unable to verify/create output bucket testbucket. Provided s3://testbucket/one/2018-02-06/
> 3. Unable to verify/create output bucket testbucket. Provided testbucket

Can someone help me out with the right s3 format?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The output location needs to be in the following format:

```
s3://{bucketname}/{path}
```

In your case this would lead to the following location:

```
resultConfig.OutputLocation = "s3://testbucket/one/2018-02-06/";
```

Comment: I have tried this as well . Check the second exception case. It fails

Comment: It says that you do not own "testbucket". You have to use a bucket that you can access.

Comment: I have updated the error for case 2 & 3 .It says unable to verify or create bucket. The profile has all privileges to read and write in s3.

Comment: I'm connecting using Simba Athena ODBC Driver. The format worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
Amazon.Athena.AmazonAthenaClient _client = new Amazon.Athena.AmazonAthenaClient(AwsAccessKeyId, AwsSecretAccessKey, EndPoint);
                Amazon.Athena.Model.ResultConfiguration resultConfig = new Amazon.Athena.Model.ResultConfiguration();
                resultConfig.OutputLocation = "s3://"+BucketName+"/key1/";                
                string query = "SELECT * FROM copalanadev.logs";
                //Populate the request object
                Amazon.Athena.Model.StartQueryExecutionRequest queryExec = new Amazon.Athena.Model.StartQueryExecutionRequest();
                queryExec.QueryString = query;
                //queryExec.QueryExecutionContext = queryExecutionContext;
                queryExec.ResultConfiguration = resultConfig;

            StartQueryExecutionResponse athenaResponse = _client.StartQueryExecution(queryExec);//throws exception
```